# Is there a scheme structure on the real line (with the cofinite topology)?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

One of the first conundrums one encounters when learning about schemes is that the affine real line $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{R}^1 = \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x]$ as *a lot* more points than the $x$-axis "real line" we know and love from, say, Euclidean geometry. These extra points aren't just generic points: there is a closed point in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{R}^1$ corresponding to every polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ (we can thus think of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{R}^1$ as a quotient of the complex "line" $\mathbb{C}$ by the action of the conjugation automorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}: z \mapsto \overline{z}$).

In many other fields, the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) is given status as a *bona fide* object, without extra points. My question is thus the following:

> Is there a scheme $X$, the set $X_\mathrm{cl}$ of closed points of which, with the topology induced from the Zariski topology, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology?

My intuition says "no", for what would the structure sheaf on such a scheme be (could it possibly be an $\mathbb{R}$-scheme?), but I have been unable to come up with a disproof.

Comment: Is your question about $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology or with the cofinite topology?

Comment: In my highlighted question, I ask with the cofinite topology. Should I clarify in the main post?

Comment: I mean, the title of your post pretty clearly suggests that you're asking about the usual topology.

Comment: I'll clarify in the title.

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$, then $X_{cl}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology because they have the same cardinality, right?

Comment: 1. yes. the affine line over the complex numbers + pick your favorite bijection between C and R (it will automatically be bicontinuous for the cofinite topologies). 2. No. any subspace of R is hausdorff. Only zero-dimensional schemes are Hausdorff, but they are totally disconnected. An open subset of R is not totally disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly.  For instance, let $k$ be any field of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  Then the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ (or any other irreducible curve over $k$) have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ and has the cofinite topology.  Any bijection between the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is then a homeomorphism (for the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$), and by transfer of structure gives a scheme structure whose closed points are $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right; we overlooked the obvious! Perhaps the question was not particularly interesting in the first place.